# Can't get png image sequence to display using flipbook jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image, png, sequence

I'm trying to loop a png image sequence on a web page using "flipbook" (http://inscopeapps.com/demos/flipbook/)

No matter what I seem to try, the demo I'm trying to create ends up with a blank page (http://dsdmdesign.com/guard/guard.html)

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.guard {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js>
</script>
<script src="jquery.flipbook.js"></script>
<img class="guard" images="guard.%3d.png" start="1" end="10" fps="24" mobileStep="3" />
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to get the image sequence to show up correctly?  I am very much a newbie to using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't ever initializing your flipbook. Something like...

([Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLv2s/2/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('img.guard').flipbook({
            'mobileStep': 1
        });
    });
</script>
```